# Android - Error connecting with login URI

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, ssl

I'm trying to connect a google spreadsheet in my code. It worked for a while, but lately it stopped working.
It started after I moved my workspace to another directory. I did not change anything else...
Here is the error:

```
06-01 17:04:56.108: W/System.err(1290): com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:549)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at googleDriveConnection.MySpreadsheetIntegration.<init>(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:59)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at googleDriveConnection.MySpreadsheetIntegration.Instance(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:45)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at smsManaging.SmsSendRunnable.run(SmsSendRunnable.java:60)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jun 01 17:04:56 GMT+00:00 2014, validation time: Wed Jun 04 08:58:29 GMT+00:00 2014
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:477)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:185)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:378)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
06-01 17:04:56.118: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.makePostRequest(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:611)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:547)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     ... 8 more
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jun 01 17:04:56 GMT+00:00 2014, validation time: Wed Jun 04 08:58:29 GMT+00:00 2014
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:161)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:664)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:474)
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290):     ... 17 more
06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290): Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jun 01 17:04:56 GMT+00:00 2014, validation time: Wed Jun 04 08:58:29 GMT+00:00 2014
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertA(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1521)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:399)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:197)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:156)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     ... 20 more
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException: current time: Sun Jun 01 17:04:56 GMT+00:00 2014, validation time: Wed Jun 04 08:58:29 GMT+00:00 2014
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:163)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:157)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertA(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1512)
06-01 17:04:56.138: W/System.err(1290):     ... 23 more
```

I searched all this forum, and found somthing similar that didn't help me - [com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909504/com-google-gdata-util-authenticationexception-error-connecting-with-login-uri)

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 12):

> 06-01 17:04:56.128: W/System.err(1290): Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jun 01 17:04:56 GMT+00:00 2014, validation time: Wed Jun 04 08:58:29 GMT+00:00 2014

Set your system (phone/emulator) date time to current date time, it is failing to validate certification because of date time mismatch

Comment: Working fine..also how to handle this in code...since in response you will get just Network Error. any suggestion ?